# Generate random number bounded between two numbers in Java Card

Tags: random, javacard

How to generate random number bounded between two number in Java Card? For example number should be generated between 0 and 50.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: use RandomData abstract class

Answer (score 6):

Note that I have only tested the distribution of the random numbers using `SecureRandom` within Java SE. I'm reasonably sure that this code is correct though. The code uses the "simple reject" method defined by NIST.

So without further ado, the code.

```java
package nl.owlstead.jcsecurerandom;

import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.RandomData;

/**
 * Generates numbers within a range. This class uses modulo arithmetic to
 * minimize the number of calls to the random number generator without expensive
 * calculations. The class is similar in operation to the
 * {@code SecureRandom.nextInt(int)} method defined in Java SE.
 * 
 * @author owlstead
 */
public final class JCSecureRandom {

    private static final short SHORT_SIZE_BYTES = 2;
    private static final short START = 0;

    private final RandomData rnd;
    private final byte[] buf;

    /**
     * Constructor which uses the given source of random bytes. A two byte
     * buffer transient buffer is generated that is cleared on deselect.
     * 
     * @param rnd
     *            the source of random bytes
     */
    public JCSecureRandom(final RandomData rnd) {
        this.rnd = rnd;
        this.buf = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(SHORT_SIZE_BYTES,
                JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a single short with a random value in the range of 0
     * (inclusive) to the given parameter n (exclusive).
     * 
     * @param n
     *            the upper bound of the random value, must be positive
     *            (exclusive)
     * @return the random value in the range [0..n-1]
     */
    public short nextShort(final short n) {
        final short sn = (short) (n - 1);
        short bits, val;
        do {
            bits = next15();
            val = (short) (bits % n);
        } while ((short) (bits - val + sn) < 0);
        return val;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a single byte with a random value in the range of 0 (inclusive)
     * to the given parameter n (exclusive).
     * 
     * @param n
     *            the upper bound of the random value, must be positive
     *            (exclusive)
     * @return the random value in the range [0..n-1]
     */
    public byte nextByte(final byte n) {
        if ((n & -n) == n) {
            return (byte) ((n * next7()) >> 7);
        }

        final byte sn = (byte) (n - 1);
        byte bits, val;
        do {
            bits = next7();
            val = (byte) (bits % n);
        } while ((byte) (bits - val + sn) < 0);
        return val;
    }

    /**
     * Generates 15 bits from two bytes by setting the highest bit to zero.
     * 
     * @return the positive valued short containing 15 bits of random
     */
    private short next15() {
        this.rnd.generateData(this.buf, START, SHORT_SIZE_BYTES);
        return (short) (Util.getShort(this.buf, START) & 0x7FFF);
    }

    /**
     * Generates 7 bits from one byte by setting the highest bit to zero.
     * 
     * @return the positive valued byte containing 7 bits of random
     */
    private byte next7() {
        this.rnd.generateData(this.buf, START, SHORT_SIZE_BYTES);
        return (byte) (this.buf[START] & 0x7F);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also proposed an API change for Java Card, but it was never taken up unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In Java Card, you only have access to the javacard.security.RandomData, which is only able to generate random bytes.

You first need a variable of the right type:

```
private RandomData rng;
private byte[] rndBuffer;
```

Then, you need the following code in your constructor/install (to avoid allocating a random generator and buffer every time):

```
rng = RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
rndBuffer = JCSystem.getTransientByteArray(JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT, 1);
```

And then, you can define your method to get a random byte in a range:

```
byte getRandomByteInRange(byte min, byte max) {
  do {
    rng.generateData(rndBuffer,0,1);
  while ((rndBuffer[0]<min) || (rndBuffer[0]>max))
  return rndBuffer[0];
}
```

There is most likely a less stupid way to write this method (especially for small ranges), but it should work.

Comment: Please test your code. `getTransientByteArray` does not exist, the order of the parameters is incorrect, and testing against the value directly is extremely naive. Furthermore, I don't think the minimal value and maximum value should both be exclusive. Normally it is from min (inclusive) to max (exclusive). Something could be said about inclusive to inclusive, but I don't think anybody would expect a range from 0 to 2 just to be able to deliver the value 1. Once for each 256 on average too.

Comment: Be gentle with Eric, @owlstead, he's new on SO. ;)

Answer (score -1):

There are  [examples](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62) here. Taking the example 2 from that link:

```
import java.util.Random;

/** Generate random integers in a certain range. */
public final class RandomRange {

 public static final void main(String... aArgs){
  log("Generating random integers in the range 1..10.");

  int START = 1;
  int END = 10;
  Random random = new Random();
  for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
   showRandomInteger(START, END, random);
  }

  log("Done.");
}

private static void showRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd, Random aRandom){
  if ( aStart > aEnd ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
 }
 //get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
 long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;
 // compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
 long fraction = (long)(range * aRandom.nextDouble());
 int randomNumber =  (int)(fraction + aStart);    
 log("Generated : " + randomNumber);
}

private static void log(String aMessage){
 System.out.println(aMessage);
 }
}
```

Comment: that's is in java,I want same result in javaCard

Answer (score -1):

use RandomData abstract class:

http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/RandomData.html

Edit:

here is an exaple of this class in use,

```
byte[] keyBytes = JCSystem.getTransientByteArray(COD,16);

RandomData rng = RandomData.getInstance(ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
rng.generateData(keyBytes,0,16);
```

If you are simply looking for random number instead of randomData you can use this:

```
    /*
    * generate a random number between 0 and 50
    */
    Random random1 = new Random();
    int card = (random1.nextInt(51));
```

Comment: I was see this link but I didn't knew how to use this function,could you give me an example please

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of the RandomData class in use

Comment: thank you for your repley,i want same result of seconde example:int card = (random1.nextInt(51)); but in javaCard because this Random is not available in java card API 2.2.2

Comment: Neither is `int` most of the time.